# Strings are the same but if/then is saying they are not equal

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to make a script to get the latest version of a GitHub project and check if it has been updated. The script is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
getVersion(){
    curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/pwn20wndstuff/Undecimus/releases/latest" |
        grep '"tag_name":' |
        sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'
}
writeVersion(){
    func_result="$(getVersion)"
    echo $func_result > version.txt
}

checkForUpdate(){
    currentVersion=$(cat version.txt)
    latestVersion="$(getVersion)"
    if [ "$currentVersion" == "$version" ]; then
        echo "Strings are equal"
    else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
        echo "current version is: $currentVersion"
        echo "latest version is: $latestVersion"
    fi
}
```

output of `./get_latest_release.sh checkForUpdate`:

```
Strings are not equal 
current version is: v4.2.1 
latest version is: v4.2.1
```

As you can see, the versions are the same yet the `if then` check is returning that they are different rather than `Strings are equal`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's probably differences in whitespace.

Comment: Try surrounding the values printed with quotes, then the whitespace will be apparent.

Comment: The first step in debugging a script should be to put `set -x` at the beginning. It will then trace the execution, and show all the variables.

Comment: Make sure `version.txt` doesn't have a CRLF at the end of the line.

Comment: I changed it to   echo "current version is: "$currentVersion""
  echo "latest version is: "$latestVersion""  but the white space does not show

Comment: Put single quotes around the variables. Double quotes are just ending the string that starts with `current`

Comment: Try `echo "$currentVersion" | hexdump -C` and `echo "$latestVersion" | hexdump -C`. Or the same with `| xxd -p`

Comment: Looks like there is a CRLF at the end of the file, I am writing to it using echo, how do I tell it to not do that

Comment: `echo` isn't doing it, it's coming from the `curl` response.

Comment: `echo "$currentVersion" | xxd; echo "$latestVersion" | xxd` - first of all compare hexadecimal dumps of strings...

Comment: 00000000: 7634 2e32 2e31 0a                        v4.2.1.
00000000: 7634 2e32 2e31 0a                        v4.2.1.

Comment: And where the `version` variable assigned? Mistyping?

Comment: Damn it. Such a simple thing. Thank you! Would have taken me hours to notice

Comment: http://www.linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html `-u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.` - it is useful for debugging. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check

```
if [ "$currentVersion" == "$version" ]; then
```

should be

```
if [ "$currentVersion" == "$latestVersion" ]; then
```

Comment: Use `[[` in bash.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes, `[[..]]` is better. I could alse advise using `${currentVersion}` (with curly braces), combining `grep` and `sed` in one command in `getVersion()`, and use quotes and curly braces in `echo $func_result > version.txt`, but I wanted to make clear what the main problem was without too much distraction.